# Is it possible to save data directly to django without using forms?

Tags: python, django, database

If I have a model like this:

```
class SomeClass(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    field1 = models.FloatField()
    field2 = models.FloatField()
    field3 = models.FloatField()
    field4 = models.FloatField()
    field5 = models.FloatField()
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

and I have a set of data, for example
`data_list = ('title', 10, 20, 30, 40, 50)`

How can I save data directly without asking for input to user, or using forms?

thanks

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/models/#field-options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple options as specified in the [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/queries/#creating-objects)

One way to do it is:

```
some_obj = SomeClass(title="title", field1=10, field2=20, field3=30, field4=40, field5=50)
some_obj.save()
```

Using your `data_list`, you may do something like:

```
some_obj = SomeClass(title=data_list[0], field1=data_list[1], field2=data_list[2], field3=data_list[3], field4=data_list[4], field5=data_list[5])
some_obj.save()
```